# How to make UIPickerView.viewForRow highlighted in the center , the reset row gray?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

How to make it more nicely?

Like the following image: the center row is highlighted, the rest row gray.

[image: 000]

Here is code:

```
extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate{

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let info = BeatScalar.generalRates[row]
        let general = GeneralRateItem(info.cn, info.ita, info.val)
        // gray every row
        general.unselected()
        decorateView(pickerView, row: row)
        return general
    }


    // Here is the logic 
    func decorateView(_ picker: UIPickerView, row: Int){

        var frame = picker.frame
        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height * 0.42
        frame.size.height = frame.size.height * 0.16

        let mini = max(row-1, 0)
        //   19 is total number
        let maxi = min(18, row+1)
        for i in mini...maxi{
            if i != row, let item = picker.view(forRow: i, forComponent: 0) as? GeneralRateItem{
                let f = item.convert(item.frame, to: picker)
                if frame.intersects(f) == false{
                    // highlight the center row
                    item.selected()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }
}


extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {       // 19 is total number
        return 19
    }
}
```

more code in [github](https://github.com/ForStackO/picker)

I need to use `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow`, because

[image: 22]

The code above works fine, the drawback is that it calculates much, and hard coded with some math.

I don't really know the logic. I think the logic result is just the opposite.

while Xcode always reports,

> [Assert] Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is not allowed. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForCellForRowAtIndexPathAccessDuringUpdate to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur. Perhaps you are trying to ask the table view for a cell from inside a table view callback about a specific row? Table view: ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 19}; contentSize: {314, 836}; adjustedContentInset: {127.66666666666667, 0, 127.33333333333331, 0}; dataSource: ; layer = >>

**How to improve the code?**

---

I have an other idea,

access the pickerView's subview to do it

[image: 3333]

How to do it more neatly?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/47048600/10150796

Comment: The effect is not good as mine, `pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component) == row ` , you can check my code.

Comment: My code crashes in device, works on simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "\(value(forRow: row))"
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    DispatchQueue.main.async {  // chance color of the middle row
        if let label = pickerView.view(forRow: row, forComponent: component) as? UILabel {
            label.textColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
    return label
}
```

#### How it actually works behind the curtains:

`UIPickerView` contains from 3 diffrent `UITableViews`. For top, middle and bottom part (my case is transformed, don't mind that).

[image: UIPickerView layout]

Function `viewForRow` provider returns `view`, but you don't know for which part is the `view` provided for. But when you ask for `view` via `pickerView.view(forRow: row, forComponent: component)` it always returns you the one in the middle, then you can do your styling. Reason why it's in `DispatchQueue.main.async` is that you have to wait until `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView` has ended by scheduling it to the end of the render `queue`.